# How do I report scammers on Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-hangouts, google-feedback

How do I report scammers on Hangouts? They are fake scam profiles I have found on media sites, not fakebook... other sites full of scammers. They contact me and send me more fake pics, usually of porn models. I'm keeping a list of their Hangout addresses. But where do I go from here?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

- click on **3 lines** or **3 dots**:

  [image: 0]

---

- click on **Settings** or **Help & Feedback**:

  [image: 0]

---

- click on **Feedback** or **Send Feedback**:

  [image: 0]

---

- include all your issues, evidence, etc. and send it:

  [image: 0]

---

- also note that you can **Hide** or **Block** people

  [image: 0]

Comment: do u know how long it takes google to delete scam profiles?  Do they even reply to the feedback?

Comment: @andym it could be hours or even days and unfortunately they rarely reply so do not expect a full report of all actions they took. also, please read: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers